# VBA - Automatically Filtering Table & Pasting to New Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, filter

My code currently takes data from a table, filters the data by criteria in a column, and then it pastes the data in a specific location on a separate sheet.

I am trying to have it copy all columns except for ColumnQ of the filtered data, and paste as values onto a different sheet.

My current code is on top, however I want it to function like the second bit of code.

```
Dim dndWS As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set dndWS = wb.Worksheets("DO NOT DELETE")

With dndWS
   .AutoFilterMode = False
   With .Range("H3:Q500")
       .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criterial1:="ColumnQ"
       .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wb.Worksheets("MASTER").Range("A22:I57")
   End With
End With
```

I want the code to function as such:

```
Dim dndWS As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set dndWS = wb.Worksheets("DO NOT DELETE")

    With dndWS
       .AutoFilterMode = False
       With .Range("H3:Q500")
           .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criterial1:="ColumnQ"
           ONLY SELECT/COPY RANGE H:P FROM FILTERED TABLE
           PASTE AS VALUES TO wb.Worksheets("MASTER").Range("A22:I57")
       End With
     End With
```

Comment: As far as I know you have three options: 1) loop through the entire data range, skipping column Q, writing all values into an array, then paste that into the target sheet, then format everything.  2) copy/paste in two operations, once for cols A-P, then again for R+.  3) copy/paste once, copying all columns, then delete Q from the new sheet.  I think 3 is probably the easiest.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland I went with option 3. Simplest, yet most effective. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have three options: 1) loop through the entire data range, skipping column Q, writing all values into an array, then paste that into the target sheet, then format everything. 2) copy/paste in two operations, once for cols A-P, then again for R+. 3) copy/paste once, copying all columns, then delete Q from the new sheet. I think 3 is probably the easiest.